# Why dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:) is nil outside the cellForItemAtIndexPath function scope?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hi I was trying to modify UICollectionView's cell in NSFetchedResultsController's delegate function

```
controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?)
```

by means of dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:) function. But it always returns nil. So I had to use cellForItemAtIndexPath function. But why dequeueReusableCell returns nil. Of course I had registered class before.

```
 collectionView?.register(MessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
```

Here is code:

```
   if type == .update {
        print("UPDATE")
        blockOperations.append(BlockOperation(block: {              
           let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath!)
             as! MessageCell          
 //   let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.cellId, for: indexPath!)  returns nil. why?
            let friend = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath!) as! Friend               
            cell.message = friend.lastMessage

        }))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you actually need `cellForItem` , second it will return a cell if it's currently visible

```
   collec.cellForItem(at: NSIndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0  ) as IndexPath)
```

Comment: This is COLLECTIOVIEW

Answer (score 0):

You must not modify UICollectionView's cell outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, in `NSFetchedResultsController`'s delegate function edit your underlying `data model` and call `reloadData` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`.

And `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` must be used only inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I there any docs says about "And dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier must be used only inside cellForRowAtIndexPath."

Comment: even so this is does not explained why dequeRusablecell returns nil

Comment: In the 'Discussion' part of official documentation for the function.

Comment: It supposed to return nil if there are no reusable cells available. In this case, you must allocate a new cell with initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: or use the new method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:

Comment: Call this method from your data source object when asked to provide a new cell for the collection view.  There is no limitations of how using within source object

Comment: In this case, you must allocate a new cell with initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: or use the new method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath, i am actually using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath method

Comment: You have lost the point, "Call this method from your data source object when asked to provide a new cell for the collection view" is saying to call this ONLY when collection view ask your delegate data source to provide a new cell, which is done via cellForItemAtIndexPath callback. You are calling it in a fetch callback and in a block that is not performed on the main thread and wonder why it's not working...